# `await Task.Run(() => DoWork1Async())` instead of `await DoWork1Async()`?

Tags: c#

There are following methods,

```
async Task DoWork1Async() { .... };
async Task DoWork2Async() { .... };
async Task DoWork3Async() { .... };
```

I read the following code

```
await Task.Run(() => DoWork1Async());
await Task.Run(() => DoWork2Async());
await Task.Run(() => DoWork3Async());
```

instead of

```
await DoWork1Async();
await DoWork2Async();
await DoWork3Async();
```

What's the difference between these two?

Comment: What did you see in the documentation for `Task.Run`, since you want to know what that method does?  What about it's description did you not understand or was confusing to you?

Comment: Trying to understand what's the usage of `await Task.Run(() => DoWork1Async())`. Running in a new thread and still wait seems to not making sense.

Answer (score 2):

```
await Task.Run(() => DoWork1Async());
```

Starts a Task, which will call `DoWork1Async`.  This is guaranteed to be asynchronous no matter how `DoWork1Async` is implemented.

*Note*:  `Task.Run(Action<Task<T>>)` returns a `Task<T>`,
        *not* a `Task<Task<T>>`.  When your lambda returns a Task, Task.Run() returns a Task that completes with the result of the inner task.  Thus you do not need to do awkward things like `await await Task.Run(() => return a Task)`.

---

```
await DoWork1Async();
```

Calls `DoWork1Async` synchronously on the current thread.  If `DoWork1Async` executes an `await` statement, then work will be suspended and the remainder of the work will occur asynchronously.  However, if `DoWork1Async` completes execution without hitting an `await`, then control will return to your caller and will then start `DoWork2Async` all synchronously.

---

So in short, the first form guarantees the DoWork1Async won't start or finish synchronously.

The second form will start DoWork1Async synchronously, and may even finish it synchronously depending upon how it is written.

--
Here's a fiddle showing the difference:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/GhrO8x

Notice how in the first case `DoWork()` starts and executes completely synchronously before we even await its `Task` while in the 2nd case it executes asynchronously after we await its task.

Comment: Hey Brandon, would you update with a comment about the Task.Run unwrapping the inner Task because I found that useful.

Answer (score 2):

When you run (within a method marked `async`)

```
 await DoWork1Async();
```

your code calls `DoWork1Async` within a state machine the compiler sets up.  At that point, you code relinquishes control back to that state machine.  When the task completes, the rest of the code in your method continues.

Remember that `async` code doesn't necessarily run on a separate thread (for example, if you are doing asynchronous I/O).

When you run:

```
 await Task.Run(() => DoWork1Async());
```

your `DoWork1Async` is dispatched as work to the Thread Pool.  It is executed on a different thread (a thread pool thread).  When that work is completed, that same state machine mechanism hands control back to you code to continue running.

In the second case, your code always runs on a thread pool thread.  In the first case, you may not be using an extra thread at all (depending on how DoWork1Async is coded)